# I have a list of times which I want to put into a dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, select, dropdown

Kind of new to this, so sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

I have made a list of times, which I have to put into a select menu.
Kinda like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fIUP.png) .

I actually want my list to be from 16:00 until 01:45 or 02:00 instead of 00:00-01:45 & 16:00-23:45, but I don't know how.
And then the second thing is I couldn't manage to get this list into a

```
<select>
```

dropdown menu

This is the code I've got so far:

```
<?php 

$exclude = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

function echo_datelist($i, $j)
{
    $time = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($j, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);            
    echo $time.'<br />';
}

for ($i = 00; $i <= 23; $i++)
{ 
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+=15)
    { 
        if (in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
        echo_datelist($i, $j); 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start at 16:00 and go to 1:45 you could use a modulus like so inside your first for loop `$t = ($i + 16) % 24` and then use this variable instead of $i inside you other loop. If you want to put it in a select element you need to surround your loop with `<select>` `</select>` here is an example of what you are looking for.

```
<?php
$exclude = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

function echo_datelist($i, $j)
{
    $time = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($j, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);            
    echo "<option value=" .$time. ">" . $time . "</option>"; // print in option
}
echo "<select>"; // this to enclose it all in a select element
for ($i = 00; $i <= 23; $i++){
    $hour = ($i + 16) % 24; // this to start at 16:00 and wrap around to 1:45
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+=15)
    {  
        if (in_array($hour, $exclude)) continue;
        echo_datelist($hour, $j); 
    }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for! Just one more extra question came up, is there also a way to add "02:00" to the bottom of the menu, and maybe something like "as soon as possible" to the top?

Comment: Yup you can. just add it as an option where you need it. for example right after the first `<select>` tag you can add this.
`echo "<option value=''>As soon as possible </option>";`

Comment: right before the closing `</select>` you can add `echo_datelist(2,0);` to add 2:00

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) which will generate the time you want with [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to handle the key and the value for your dropdown.

So, for example,

```
$fromTime = mktime(16, 0, 0, 11, 8, 2017); // (11-08-2017 16:00:00)
$toTime   = mktime(2, 0, 0, 11, 9, 2017); // (11-09-2017 02:00:00)

$i = 15; // every 15 mins
$timePointer = $fromTime;
while($timePointer <= $toTime) {
    $timesList[$timePointer] = date('H:i', $timePointer);
    $timePointer += $i * 60; // mult by 60 to convert to minutes
}

print_r($timesList);
```